# Android Studio: Using radioButtons for a quiz

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

So I'm trying to make an app where you select an answer from a `radioButton` within a `radioGroup`, and when you hit the Submit button it will change the `textbox` to say "Correct" or "Wrong answer", depending on which button was selected. I'm able to run the app, and select the `radioButton`, but when I click submit, the app crashes and says "Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped".

This is the code that I have:

XML

```
 <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/question1"
    android:id="@+id/q1radiobox">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/q1a1"
            android:id="@+id/q1a1" />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/q1a2"
            android:id="@+id/q1a2"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/q1a3"
            android:id="@+id/q1a3"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/q1a4"
            android:id="@+id/q1a4"/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:onClick="checkResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/q1radiobox"
        android:text="Submit"/>
```

Java

```
   private void checkResult() {
      RadioButton rb;
      rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.q1a3);

      if (rb.isChecked()) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1)).setText("@string/correct");
      } 
      else {
          ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1)).setText("@string/incorrect");
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated; I can't work out what's wrong!

EDIT: I have posted the solution. Credit to @miselking for pointing out one of the issues.

Comment: post the error message on your log cat.

Comment: I am not still seeing it.

Comment: Sorry, all the pending edit wanted was to change "XML" to lowercase.

Comment: The log is telling you that you are calling a function called checkForResult with view argument but your function does not seem to take any argumet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all of this hassle, I have found that the issues were as follows:

```
 private void checkResult()
```

Needed to be

```
public void checkResult(View view)
```

Thank you to @miselking for pointing out the lack of a view, and I found the public/private void by pure luck, when playing around with the method.

Comment: No problem, sorry it took me a while to write an explanation in an edit, hope it helps...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so what you need to know it that when you are using `android:onClick="checkResult"` way of defining the click events, your `checkResult` method needs to have the `View` as an argument, only then it can respond to onClick events. So, change your method to something like this:

```
    private void checkResult(View v) {
      RadioButton rb;
      rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.q1a3);

      if (rb.isChecked()) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1)).setText("@string/correct");
      } 
      else {
          ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1)).setText("@string/incorrect");
    }
```

EDIT: What you are getting is a warning, not an error. You are getting that warning because you are not using the parameter `v` anywhere in your method. You can ignore it, it is usefull if you have multiple buttons invoking the same method, then you need to know which button actually invoked the method.

Let's say you have two buttons with ids `btnId1` and `btnId2`. Both of them have this line of code in xml file: `android:onClick="checkResult"`, so both of them call the same method (you can do that). Then, when you click any of these two buttons, which one actually invoked the method? Well, that is why the `View v` is neccessary. Then, you would have been able to see which button was actually clicked and responded appropriatelly. Example of implementation of the `checkResult`:

```
public void checkResult(View view)
    {
        Log.d("TAG_BTN", "Someone called me. But who???");
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btnId1:
                Log.d("TAG_BTN", "BtnId1 called me. Do something, please...");
                break;
            case R.id.btnId2:
                Log.d("TAG_BTN", "BtnId2 called me. What next to do...");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Hopefully, you know understand why you need the `View` parameter.

Comment: I have already tried this, it hasn't made a difference. When I hover over the "View v" section of the code, it says "Parameter 'v' is never used".

Comment: Thank you for the edit, yes that has cleared up the use of View! Very well explained.